# SonarQube Scan is not working on ASP.net Website

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, static-code-analysis, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have one application that has both VB.net project and ASP.net website (written in VB). VB.net project has .sln file. ASP.net website was added to that solution. Build works fine. When I try to run SonarQube scan, VB.net files are identified and results have been posted on SonarQube. But ASP.net website folder is not even taken for the scan. I am just wondering whether I will be able to run Sonar scan on ASP.net website. Will there be any changes that need to be done in the .sln file? Does SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe have any dependency with .sln file?

Comment: Did you inspect the SonarQube logging?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks for the response. I did inspect the SonarQube logs. No errors. There are two folders in root. One for project and another one web site. Sonar simply skips the web site.